# How can I exclude the arm64-v8a dir from the fresco(android lib of facebook)

Tags: android, gradle

[image]

Just as you see,the Fresco has arm64-v8a dir,but I do not want it.What should I write in build.gradle

```
compile('com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.5.3') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids'
    exclude group: 'imagepipeline/jni/arm64-v8a'
}
```

Comment: Just wondering why do you want to exclude the native code that most likely the library need to operate?

Comment: There is another lib that has not the arm64-v8a dir,If I don't exclude the arm64-v8a dir of Freco,the app will crash on arm64 platform

Comment: The only good reason to exclude this directory is if you don't plan on shipping your app to devices running with that hardware, such as the Samsung S6. If the issue is a conflict with another library, can you tell us the name of the library?

Answer (score 5):

Write below code in build.gradle file of your app

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86","armeabi"
        }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/mysofile.so"
        }
    }
}
```

Replace mysofile.so by your .so file

Comment: packagingOptions exclude saved me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

this may help: [Shipping Multiple APKs](http://frescolib.org/docs/multiple-apks.html#_)

> If your application is not used by devices running Android 2.3
>   (Gingerbread), you will not need the armeabi flavor.
>
> Android Studio / Gradle# Edit your build.gradle file as follows:
>
> ```
> android {
>   // rest of your app's logic
>   splits {
>     abi {
>         enable true
>         reset()
>         include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'armeabi'
>         universalApk false
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add entry in packagingOptions under android/app/build.gradle file **android** section as shown below to exclude the particular file or entire folder from apk lib folder

```
 splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        packagingOptions({
            exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/*' //instead of * you can specify perticualr so file name also
            exclude 'lib/x86_64/*'
        })
    }
}
```